# Регулярное выражение для поиска хостнеймов через запятые

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, django

Мне нужно регулярное выражение для джанго, которое бы находило в тексте строки вроде

```
"example.com,www.example.com,subdomain.example.com".
```

То, что у меня сейчас имеется, - `"([[a-z.]*[a-z0-9-_]+\.[a-z]{1,3}]*[?:,|$]*)"` - находит только самый первый хостнейм.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделай поиск глобальным, без остановок после первого найденного значения, т.е.

```
([[a-z.]*[a-z0-9-_]+\.[a-z]{1,3}]*[?:,|$]*)/g
```